# Why is it necessary for IntStream's foreach() to receive an argument for IntConsumer's accept()?

Tags: methods, lambda, interface

I'm reading up an ebook and currently onto Lambdas - Stream.
Kindly take a look at the first part of the code.

```
int[] values = {3, 10, 6, 1, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 7};

// display original values
System.out.print("Original values: ");
IntStream.of(values)
         .forEach(value -> System.out.printf("%d ", value));
System.out.println();
```

The book explains that `IntStream` method `forEach`(a terminal operation) performs a task on each stream element. The method receives an object as its argument that implements the `IntConsumer` functional interface(package java.util.function). This interface's `accept` method receives one int value and performs a task with it.

Furthermore, it says that prior to Java SE 8 we would typically implement interface IntConsumer using an anonymous inner class:

```
new IntConsumer()
{
    public void accept(int value)
    {   
        System.out.printf("%d ", value);
    }
}
```

Now my question is why do we need an instance of IntConsumer in order to invoke the method?

Comment: Can you please rephrase this part: "why would we pass an interface method's argument to another interface's method"? It's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I meant as in why do we invoke the `forEach` method with an argument to `IntConsumer`'s accept()? I'm thinking whether this has something to do with inheritance which i'm still kinda confused with.

Comment: Your understanding isn't exactly right. `forEach` accepts a single instance of `IntConsumer`. That instance may be whatever you like. If you use lambda, this instance will be instance of some class generated by compiler. Implementation of `forEach` will repeatedly call method `accept(int)` of the instance you have passed into it. That's pretty much all. If you still confused, you can look up any implementation of `forEach` in JDK code base, all of them will be very similar with some differences in minor details. `java.util.Collection::forEach` is the perfect example implementation, I find.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov i see but why is it that we need a single instance of `IntConsumer` for `forEach`? I'm so confused now even the Java API doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: You confused why does it need only single or why does it need one at all? It needs one at all because that's what method argument signature tells it, the same as passing a `Collection<T>` to something like `addAll` method - `Collection<T>` is an interface, and `addAll` states that it needs a single instance of some collection it can work with, and you can pass something like a `HashSet<T>` to it. Same with `IntConsumer`. You can easily make a `class MyConsumer implements IntConsumer`, instantiate it and pass into `forEach`, similar thing with lambdas, except compiler makes `MyConsumer` for you

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Oh you are guessing it right. I don't understand why it even needs an instance. Erm but `IntConsumer` doesn't mention about having an instance to work with. Is it that for functional interfaces, we need an instance to invoke their methods within? Sorry for taking so much of your precious time here and I really appreciate your patience.

Comment: Functional interface is simply a naming convention for an interface with single _abstract_ method (it can have as many `default` methods as you like). For all other intents and purposes it is just an interface, and to work with it in any way you have to implement it, and that implies having an instance of some class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136378/discussion-between-scorpiorian83-and-m-prokhorov).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Okie I have another question relating to the object thingy. Why is it that we create a new object instance using the interface? I thought we cannot instantiate an interface? Thanks!